# How to rotate a pseudo-element's content value

Tags: css, rotation, pseudo-element

Since pseudo-elements are inline, and you can't transform inline elements, how can I make rotation work on a pseudo-element's content value?

```
content:"\24B6"?
```

I'm trying to rotate a Unicode symbol.

Comment: Are you trying to rotate the pseudo-element once-off(30deg), or infinitely rotate it? Did not specify.

Answer (score 459, accepted):

Inline elements can't be transformed, and pseudo elements are inline by default, so you must apply `display: block` or `display: inline-block` to transform them:

```css
#whatever:after {
  content: "\24B6";
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="whatever">Some text </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.process-list:after{
    content: "\2191";
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    right:-8px;
    background-color: #ea1f41;
    width:35px;
    height: 35px;
    border:2px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 10000;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(50deg) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: rotate(50deg) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(50deg) translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: rotate(50deg) translateY(-50%);
    transform: rotate(50deg) translateY(-50%);
}
```

you can check this code . i hope you will easily understand.

Comment: Actually I don't easily understand :) A useful answer would explain what the code does, and how it's different from the accepted answer. It would also be a runnable snippet, like the accepted answer.