# How to change the symbol when click in css?

Tags: css

How can I change the symbol to "V" when click the widget title, after click back the widget title will change back the symbol ">".

image before click: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d59tJ.png)

This is my css that added after the widget title.

```
.widgettitle a::after {
    content: " >";
        font-size:16px;
        color:#d3db2c!important;
}
```

Comment: I think this cannot be done in pure CSS. You either need to add a hidden `<input type=checkbox>` to your HTML and then add some pretty fancy CSS rules, or (probably best solution) to use JavaScript.

Comment: Hi VXp, it is a collapsible widget like the drop down menu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css rotate a pseudo :after or :before content:""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779919/css-rotate-a-pseudo-after-or-before-content)

Answer (score 1):

```js
    $(".greater").click(function(){
var test = $( this ).hasClass( "greater" );


if(test){
$( this ).removeClass( "greater" );   
  $( this ).addClass( "less" );   
}else{
  $( this ).removeClass( "less" );   
  $( this ).addClass( "greater" );   
  
}
});
```

```css
.widgettitle .greater::after {
 content: " >";
 font-size:16px;
 color:#d3db2c!important;
}

.widgettitle .less::after {
 content: " v";
 font-size:16px;
 color:#d3db2c!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="widgettitle">
 <a href="#" class="greater">test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: After change to"V",so when I click back "test" can make it back to ">"

Answer (score 1):

`:active` mean when click on `a`

```css
.widgettitle a::after {
    content: " ►";
}
.widgettitle a:active::after {
    content: " ▼";
        font-size:16px;
        color:black!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="widgettitle">
<a href="#">back</a>
</div>
```

**To your comment**

> Can make it after click it will remain ▼, then click back will change
>   back to ►

**Use toggle class**

```css
.widgettitle a::after {
    content: " ►";
}
.widgettitle .toggle::after {
    content: " ▼";
        font-size:16px;
        color:black!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="widgettitle">
<a href="#" onclick="this.classList.toggle('toggle');">back</a>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: Can make it after click it will remain ▼, then click back will change back to ►?

Comment: Tell me if it helps you

Comment: because I am using WordPress, so it will need using pure css.

Comment: I think you can use js in wordPress google search please

Comment: Did u know how to add onclick="this.classList.toggle('toggle');" into my a href using wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

You've to use checkbox hack to achieve this in pure CSS:

```css
.link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.link:after {
  content: '►';
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.checkbox:checked ~ .link:after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="link-container">
    <label for="checkbox-1">Click me</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" class="checkbox">
    <a href="#" class="link"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with JavaScript. Hope its help.

```css
.widgettitle a::after {
     content: " >";
     font-size:16px;
     color:#d3db2c!important;
    }

    .newclass a:focus::after {
       content: "v";
    }
```

```html
<div id="wg" class="widgettitle">
     <a id="aid" href="#">test</a>
</div>

<script>

var aid = document.getElementById("aid");
var wg = document.getElementById("wg");
aid.onclick = function(){
 wg.classList.toggle("newclass");
}

</script>
```