# whet CSS pseudo element is not rotating

Tags: javascript, html, css, pseudo-element

here's simple html with one span item and a triangle CSS pseudo element.
I want the triangle rotate on each click, first rotate 90 degrees next click come back to original state.

When class `collapsed` is toggled also `collapsed::before` should be applied, isn't it?

The yellow color (just for debugging) but the triangle is not rotating.

What am I missing?

```js
function collapseTree(el){
    el.classList.toggle("collapsed");
}
```

```css
.span1::before{
       content: "\25B6";
      color: black;
}

.collapsed::before{
 
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari */
  transform: rotate(90deg);  
}

.collapsed{
  background: yellow;  
}

.span1{
  border: indigo 1px solid;
      color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
     }
```

```html
 <span id="span1" class="span1" onclick="collapseTree(this)">Span</span>
```

Comment: There's a question with 100+ votes on exactly the same subject. How did you not find it ? Does this answer your question? [css rotate a pseudo :after or :before content:""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779919/css-rotate-a-pseudo-after-or-before-content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set display inline-block.

```
.span1::before{
   content: "\25B6";
   color: black;
   display: inline-block;
}
```